# Update only specific field value in elasticsearch

Tags: search, indexing, elasticsearch

Is it possible to update some specific fields value in elasticsearch with out overwriting other fields. ?

Comment: yes thanks for the help.I have used script format and followed [update api](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update.html)

Answer (score 90):

As a codebased contribution to this answer, the following query may be used:

```
POST /index/type/100100471/_update
{
    "doc" : {
        "yourProperty" : 10000
    }
}
```

This query updates `yourProperty` **property only**.

As a result, this response appears:

```
{
   "_index": "index",
   "_type": "type",
   "_id": "100100471",
   "_version": 1,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 0,
      "successful": 1,
      "failed": 0
   }
}
```

Comment: I am getting `Validation Failed: 1: script or doc is missing;` - any idea why?

Comment: @rahulg The new syntax without types is POST /yourindexname/_update/youridnumber {
    "doc" : {
        "yourProperty" : 10000
    }
}

Answer (score 88):

In ES 7.3 the new format is:

```
POST /myindex/_update/mydocid
{
    "doc" : {
        "myfield": "new value of my field"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 29):

Yes, Elasticsearch supports partial updates. That means that you can submit:

- a partial document, which will be merged with the existing one
- a script that will be executed on top of the existing document

Have a look at the [update api](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update.html).
In both cases, what happens under the hood, due to how the underlying lucene library works, is that the document to be updated is retrieved, the changes are applied to it, and the old document gets overwritten with the new. At the end of the day it is in fact a complete rewrite of the document, but you don't have to submit the whole document, unless you disabled the [_source field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-source-field.html), enabled by default, which is the field that allows you to retrieve to whole document in order to apply changes to it.

Comment: As a continue could you take a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28937946/elasticsearch-particial-update-of-not-indexed-field

Comment: "If both doc and script are specified, then doc is ignored. If you specify a scripted update, include the fields you want to update in the script." https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update.html#_update_part_of_a_document

Comment: @javanna If the script checks some other document fields to update, will the script always see the latest data even if those fields haven't been refreshed for searching?

Answer (score 11):

If you would like to update the existing field value only then you must try this solution:

```
POST IndexName/_update_by_query
{
  "script": {
    "source": """

   if (ctx._source?.Field != null) 
    {  
        ctx._source.remove('Field');
        ctx._source.put('Field', 'Value');
    }   
    """,
    "lang": "painless"
  },
  "query": {
    "terms": {
        "_id": [
          1 (Replace with Document ID)
        ]
      }
  }
}
```

If you would like to add new field with value then you must try this solution:

```
POST IndexName/_update_by_query
{
  "script": {
    "source": """

   if (ctx._source?.NewField == null) 
    {  
        ctx._source.hf.put('NewField', 'Value');
    }   
    """,
    "lang": "painless"
  },
  "query": {
    "terms": {
        "_id": [
          1 (Replace with Document ID)
        ]
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: I need help to use Api Update in elasticsearch, the problem is what I have when I want to update this level further inside the structure, for example:

{
"mainLevel": [
    {
        "name": "maxi",
        "SecundaryLevel": [
            {
                "title": "Bachelor"
            }
        ]
    }
]
}

In this case the update would like to do it in "SecondaryLevel" but for a certain "MainLevel", I leave my index below.

Comment: Max you can see my below comment. So this way if you do

POST /foo_v1/_bulk?pretty=true&error_trace=true
{"update":{"_index":"foo_v1","_type":"footype","_id":"397"}}
{"doc":{"SecundaryLevel":{"title":"Married","EmailId":"married@gmail.com"}}

So this query will only update the "SecondaryLevel" object in doc and for specific id. 
I hope this answers your question. Sorry for late reply, I missed your comment earlier.

Answer (score 10):

> Update By Query API

Updates documents that match the specified query. If no query is specified, performs an update on every document in the data stream or index without modifying the source, which is useful for picking up mapping changes.

```
POST http://localhost:9200/INDEX_NAME/_update_by_query
{
  "script": {
    "source": "ctx._source.userName=new_user_name",
    "lang": "painless"
  },
  "query": { 
    "term": {
      "userName": "old_user_name"
    }
  }
}
```

In the above example, the userName field value will be updated to new_user_name

Answer (score 5):

Also you can use bulk Update to partially update multiple doc

```
POST /foo_v1/_bulk?pretty=true&error_trace=true
{"update":{"_index":"foo_v1","_type":"footype","_id":"397"}}
{"doc":{"Name":"foo","EmailId":"foo@test.com"}}
{"update":{"_index":"foo_v1","_type":"footype","_id":"398"}}
{"doc":{"Name":"foo1","EmailId":"foo1@test.com"}}
```

If you are not sure whether it will be a update or insert like Upsert so you can do :

```
POST /foo_v1/_bulk?pretty=true&error_trace=true
{"update":{"_index":"foo_v1","_type":"footype","_id":"397"}}
{"doc":{"Name":"foo","EmailId":"foo@test.com"}, "doc_as_upsert" : true}
```

use **"doc_as_upsert" : true**

Answer (score 5):

Make `POST` call to `{{host}}/{{index}}/_doc/{{id}}/_update`

with body as

```
{
    "doc": {
        "field": "value"
    }
}
```

Output would be similar to

```
{
    "_index": "{{index}}",
    "_type": "_doc",
    "_id": "{{id}}",
    "_version": 3,
    "result": "updated",
    "_shards": {
        "total": 2,
        "successful": 1,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "_seq_no": 27,
    "_primary_term": 2
}
```

Comment: The end of this URL should be `...{{index}}/_update/1`. Your alternative still works with ES 7 but everything involving the "_doc" endpoint will become illegal with ES 8! Marc's answer here in 2019 already gave the future-proof answer. You should delete yours.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
curl -XPOST --header 'Content-Type: application/json' https://search-testarticle-2cwv6oh7wtz3hxowgxv3rprnsa.ap-south-1.es.amazonaws.com/test/_update/4gI4knQB7d5sAgV24YPy -d '{
"doc":  { "name" : "Ankit Singh Raj" }
}'
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, this worked:

```
    POST /jira_project/_doc/4c459bbb-8cc2-44c0-a455-f01cfc658017/_update
    {
      "doc":{
        "body": {
          "isDeleted": true,
          "deletedAt": "2023-10-03T11:16:21.489Z"
        }
      }

    }
```

Explanation:

1. Here "jira_project" is the index name.
2. "_doc" is the type of entity you are targeting within that index (this is deprecated in newer versions since by default entities within an index are taken as doc type).
3. I have updated some keys inside the "body" key, so that's why I mentioned "body" while updating.

Everything else is self-explanatory.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).