# Partial update on field that is not indexed

Tags: java, elasticsearch

Let's consider the following situation - there are two fields in "article" document - content(string) and views(int). The views field is not indexed. The views field contains information how many times this article was read.

[From official doc](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/partial-updates.html):

> We also said that documents are immutable: they cannot be changed,
>   only replaced. The update API must obey the same rules. Externally, it
>   appears as though we are partially updating a document in place.
>   Internally, however, the update API simply manages the same
>   retrieve-change-reindex process that we have already described.

But what if we do particial update of not indexed field - will elasticsearch reindex the entire document? For example - I want to update views every time someone reads some article. If entire document is reindexed I can't do real time update (as it's too heavy operation). So I will have to work with delay, for example updates all articles the visitors have read every 3-5-10 minutes. Or I understand something wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***But what if we do particial update of not indexed field - will elasticsearch reindex the entire document?***

Yes, whilst the `views` field is not indexed individually it is part of the `_source` field.  The `_source` field contains the original JSON you sent to Elasticsearch when you indexed the document and is returned in the results if there is a match on the document during a search. The `_source` field is indexed with the document in Lucene. In your update script you are changing the `_source` field so the whole document will be re-indexed.

***Could you then evaluate the following strategy. Every time someone reads the article I send update to elastic. However refresh_interval I set to 30 seconds. Will this strategy be normal if during 30 second interval about 1000 users have read one article?***

You are still indexing the 1000 documents, 1 document will be indexed as the current document, 999 documents will be indexed marked as deleted and removed from the index during the next Lucene merge.

Comment: Thank your help. Could you then evaluate the following strategy. Every time someone reads the article I send update to elastic. However refresh_interval I set to 30 seconds. Will this strategy be normal if during 30 second interval about 1000 users have read one article? The matter is I don't want to code synchronization mechanism between db and elasticsearch.

Comment: This is very important, so in details. I have article with id=12. In 30 second interval 1000 visitors have read this article. If I send 1000 upates to elastic and after that the index refresh will be made what elastic will do: a)it will update document and index 1000 times b)it will inore 999 updates and will take into consideration only the last update in queue?