# Does non-indexed field update triggers reindexing in elasticsearch8?

Tags: elasticsearch, search, full-text-search

My index mapping is the following:

```
{
        "mappings": {
            "dynamic": False,
            "properties": {
                "query_str": {"type": "text", "index": False},
                "search_results": {
                    "type": "object", 
                    "enabled": False
                },
                "query_embedding": {
                    "type": "dense_vector",
                    "dims": 768,
                },
               
        }
    }
```

Field `search_result` is disabled. Actual search is performed only via `query_embedding`, other fields are just non-searchable data.

**If I will update `search_result` field in existing document, will it trigger reindexing**?

The [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/enabled.html) say that *"The enabled setting, which can be applied only to the top-level mapping definition and to object fields, causes Elasticsearch to skip parsing of the contents of the field entirely. The JSON can still be retrieved from the _source field, but it is not searchable or stored in any other way"*. So, it seems logical not to re-index docs if changes took place only in non-indexed part, but I'm not sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elasticsearch documents (Lucene Segments) are inmutable, so every change you make in a document will delete the document and create a new one. This is a Lucene's behavior:

> Lucene's index is composed of segments, each of which contains a
> subset of all the documents in the index, and is a complete searchable
> index in itself, over that subset. As documents are written to the
> index, new segments are created and flushed to directory storage.
> Segments are immutable; updates and deletions may only create new
> segments and do not modify existing ones. Over time, the writer merges
> groups of smaller segments into single larger ones in order to
> maintain an index that is efficient to search, and to reclaim dead
> space left behind by deleted (and updated) documents.

When you set enable:false you are just avoiding to have the field content in the searchable structures but the data still lives in Lucene.

You can see a similar answer here:

[Partial update on field that is not indexed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28937946/partial-update-on-field-that-is-not-indexed)